# Apply advanced search filter in android while getting data from locally stored Json file, in autocompletetextview / edittext

Tags: android, json, search, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I am kinda new to android with json, and the search.

I want to apply advanced search filter in my autocompletetextview / edittext, in android from json file stored in assets folder.

The json file is consists of FAQs for my app.

And now I want to create advanced search filter like in Google chrome, that if I am typing something like

> STACK

and the predictions I get in URL bar is

> STACK OVERFLOW

next row

> STACK EXCHANGE

etc.

Where

> stack

word is highlighted, with appropriate suggestions.

so, same that way I want to make my search filter that way, because there are some amount of FAQs in my json file, and when user types something like,

> *HOW PAPER IS MADE UP OF* or *METHOD OF PAPER MAKING* or *WANT TO MAKE
>   PAPER OUT OF WASTE* or *ETC.*

I hope that you got my point, and now here from given hints,
the words *made up, making, make*, all should be meant for *MAKE*, a root word for all of them.

Because my FAQ has questions and related answers (obviously), so questions might be in long format, so to retrieve best similar response, I want to create the advanced search filter.

So, my question is,

> IS THERE ANY PARTICULAR API OR ALGORITHM THAT I CAN APPLY TO ACHIEVE
>   THIS TASK?

I have researched for this for last almost 4-5 days..

What I have applied till now for reading json data is as below..

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("faq.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

and then,

```
try {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray json = jO.getJSONArray("faq");
            Log.v("faq", "faq");

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                q = e.getString("q");
                responseList.add(q);

                a = e.getString("a");

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then I set the arrayadapter.

Even I have worked with custom adapter, but that is not the issue now.

So, now in my search engine, when someone write set of keywords, the code should ignore the articles, adverbs etc.

The questions which are predicted must me sorted in relevance index.

The synonym capturing and sorting capabilities should be there.

Give the importance to recognized word to refine the relevant set of words.

May be able to add taxonomy dictionary.

So, I want this type of code / engine that can achieve the task required.

Even when user click spacebar, the sorting must be refreshed.

Is there any such API / library, that can fulfill the needs?

> And frankly speaking, I have tried many of the custom filter
>   solutions, and ALGOLIA API (not open-source, had trial for 14 days
>   only..) and others too, but these are not capable enough to solve my
>   need.

Therefore, I thank you in advance, if you can help me to achieve my task with suitable solution of api or algorithm or code or idea..

Regards.

Comment: I think I have got to one API called "LUCENE API" from Apache licence.

So, is it the same what I am looking for in my question!?

Comment: Even Solr and Elastic search are the other solutions too, and if thinking with web service then Algolia is nice solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LUCENE Apache API, for mobile version, 5.3.0 is the solution for my query, which I got finally..

The lucene search and lucene study are the different projects to deal with..